# How to unregister events for items without names created in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So we are going back and trying to clean up somethings in our code as our application started to use a lot of memory. Upon reading about WPF and memory management, we found that event handlers are among the biggest offenders. So, we already know it breaks MVVM having the handlers. How is it that we can unregister the events when we get rid of the control.

For instance if we have a user controls in a TabControl and we close the tab - we know we can unregister all the events; however, the user controls don't have any names. I guess it would be easy enough to go back and add names to these controls, but is there a way of doing it without using the name?

Here is the [link](http://pastebin.com/EtpXycgh) to the control. I used paste bin as it is too many characters to post here. With this control we see the biggest jump in memory.

Comment: How did you register the event handlers?

Comment: in added them in xaml

Comment: And what makes you think you're leaking?

Comment: Unless you maintain a reference to the control that subscribed to the event, you shouldn't be concerned about unsubscribing. You should verify you're leaking memory before you blindly follow the **events are bad** mentality.

Comment: App can use a tremendous amount of memory when looking at the task manager - we have seen upwards of 3 GB of memory being used on a system that only has 8 GB memory...so we decided to use a memory profiler...

Comment: @Michael are you saying that once the control is gc'd it should also take care of the event handlers as well. The memeory profiler (.NET Memory Profiler) warns us that we have instances that are directly rooted by an EventHandler. THis can indicate that an EventHandler has not been properly removed.

Comment: Do not believe task manager.  What did you memory profiler tell you and which profiler did you use?  Are you getting an OOM errors?  So you system only has 8 GB or memory - is it running out of memory?

Comment: @Blam .NET Memory Profiler  and it showed about the same amount of memory being used. It seemed to me that we had a big jump on this one particular control and if we kept opening that control it would keep piling on regardless of whether we closed the other tabs that had had that control in it...thats why it was able to reach that amount...

Comment: @Blam some users get out of memory errors as well. Some of our users have less than 8 GB of memory.

Comment: I have big app with lots of controls and tabs and have never had the problems you describe.  Rather than ask how to implement what you think is a solution try posting the problem.

Comment: @Blam I don't know what you mean...the app uses too much memory as users use the app after a period of time (problem). Hence us using a memory profiler and trying to implement its recommendations...it tells us we have undisposed event handlers...it seems that the garbage collector is not collecting these things...

Comment: I will stop trying to help.  What part of post a sample of a problem control is not clear?  I don't have problem with controls (and lots of them).

Comment: @Blam I have added one of the controls this is the control where we see the most increase of memory (in the task bar)

Comment: Using a third party toolkit is something you should mention in the post.  Do you have problems with any controls that are not using a third party.  I use only controls from VS / .NET and have and do not have the problems you describe.  You should not have to clean up after controls.

Comment: @Blam yes...they don't have as significant of a jump but yes they do use a lot of memory as well. I will try removing the the progressbar. I also did a bunch of styling and additions to the datagrid - like adding filtering and summary rows - however, when I remove the datagrid from the control it still has a large jump.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
foreach (var control in myTabControl.FindDescendents<UserControl>())
{
    control.EventName -= MyEventHandler;
}
```

Where the `DependencyObject.FindDescendants<T>()` extension method is defined in a static class:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindDescendants<T>(this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject 
{
    return FindDescendants<T>(parent, null, false);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> FindDescendants<T>(this DependencyObject parent, Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : DependencyObject 
{
    return FindDescendants(parent, predicate, false);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> FindDescendants<T>(this DependencyObject parent, bool deepSearch) where T : DependencyObject 
{
    return FindDescendants<T>(parent, null, deepSearch);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> FindDescendants<T>(this DependencyObject parent, Func<T, bool> predicate, bool deepSearch) where T : DependencyObject 
{
    var children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent).OfType<DependencyObject>().ToList();
    foreach (var child in children) 
    {
        var typedChild = child as T;
        if (typedChild != null && (predicate == null || predicate.Invoke(typedChild))) 
        {
            yield return typedChild;
            if (deepSearch) 
            {
                foreach (var foundDescendant in FindDescendants(child, predicate, true)) yield return foundDescendant;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            foreach (var foundDescendant in FindDescendants(child, predicate, deepSearch)) yield return foundDescendant;
        }
    }
}
```

(You could of course just have one extension method – I took the liberty of copying and pasting from a library of mine which has these overloaded versions.)

Comment: How would I know that MyEventHandler was a Click event vs a DoubleClick and to which control is it registered?

Comment: 'MyEventHandler' was just used as an example. I'm presuming that you have knowledge of your own code and which events handlers are added to which events (you say in a comment to your original post that you added them in XAML). So my code example, if used, would obviously need to be customised to do what you need (you would reference multiple control types, multiple events, whatever).

Comment: I get that this example has to be modified so if one of the user controls was a button and lets say I had many buttons - is MyEventHandler the name of the handler like MyButton_Click and if so how do I know which button is that event handler registered to. Thats the problem I have now...Can I do if its a button then unsubscribe all known button handlers???

Comment: Yes you can – `foreach (var button in myTabControl.FindDescendents<Button>()) button.Click -= MyButton_Click;` – this will unregister the MyButton_Click event from all your buttons. (Even if a button did not have this click event handler in the first place, this code will still run fine - try it)

Comment: ahhh...I will try this out now.